# Solve a system of equations using SymPy

Tags: python, sympy

I need to solve a system equation using the SymPy library in Python. For example:

```
y = x ** 2
x = 2
```

Solution: y = 4

How to do this with SymPy?

Comment: Stackoverflow is an english site, not portuguese. Consider translating it into english and providing a [mcve]

Comment: You cannot use `x` without first assigning a value to it. You should invert the order of your statements (that is: first `x = 2` , then `y = x ** 2`). Otherwise, you are kind of saying "get me x (== undefined variable) ** 2, that's undefined ** 2, which is an error"

Comment: I'm a bit late, but there is a portuguese version of the site here: https://pt.stackoverflow.com/

Answer (score 0):

```
from sympy import *
x = Symbol('x')
y = Symbol('y')
solve([y - x ** 2, x - 2], [x, y])
// [(2, 4)]
```